# executing commands when network goes down or up

Tags: bash, ubuntu, networking, networkmanager, espeak

I'm trying to get the Network Manager dispatcher to run a script when the network interface comes up or goes down. I want to execute an espeak command when the connection goes up or goes down.  ***I can get it to write to the file /tmp/log but I don't hear any sound from the espeak command*** even though I can type it directly on the terminal and it works.

The way I test it is by disconnecting my usb network card (this is the only network card I have in the machine)

I've place the executable file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`
(it's called **02-ifupdowntest**)

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2293 Mar 26  2018 01-ifupdown
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  534 Jan 23 16:42 02-ifupdowntest
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5383 Mar 27  2018 99tlp-rdw-nm
```

> See contents of **02-ifupdowntest** below:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
if [ "$2" = "up" ]; then

    echo "`date`" > /tmp/log
    echo "$1" >> /tmp/log
    echo "$2" >> /tmp/log
    echo "`/usr/bin/espeak "network up"`"

fi

if [ "$2" = "down" ]; then
    echo "$2" >> /tmp/log
    echo "`/usr/bin/espeak "network down"`"


fi

exit 0
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 64bit Linux

Comment: Your quoting around the `espeak` command seems wrong.

Comment: @Panki if I copy and pasted it to the terminal it works. I also tried taking out the double quotes... If it's wrong what should it be?

Comment: Why do you echo the command? By just writing `/usr/bin/espeak "something"` should do the job. You don't need to echo the command.

Comment: @annahri that didn't work.

Comment: ... in the sense that you didn't hear sound output or that there was an explicit error message?