# pause youtube-dl when network is disconnected and resume when it is connected again

Tags: bash, shell-script, networking, linux-mint, process-management

I am using Linux Mint 20.

I am using a vpn with a kill switch (`protonvpn-cli ks --on`).

So, if the vpn connection drops for some reason, the network get disconnected.

When the network get disconnected, my `youtube-dl` download stops permanently with the error

```
ERROR: Unable to download JSON metadata: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> (caused by URLError(gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')))
```

The issue is, I want `youtube-dl` to pause instead of closing, and resume when the connection is back.

I checked [Retry when connection disconnect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401603/retry-when-connection-disconnect-not-working) but I do not think it is relevant to my problem.

My config file looks like

```
--abort-on-error
--no-warnings
--console-title
--batch-file='batch-file.txt'
--socket-timeout 10
--retries 10
--continue
--fragment-retries 10
```

As I use batch files, I do not want to start the process from the beginning. I just want to pause the `youtube-dl` process till I get connected again and then continue the process.

How can I do that?

**Update 1:**

So far, what I have found is, to pause a process we can do something like:

```
$ kill -STOP 16143
```

To resume a process we can do something like:

```
$ kill -CONT 16143
```

I am not sure but think that we can know if my network is up or not by pinging<sup>[1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136137/206574) [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/48320/598062)</sup>:

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTS="cyberciti.biz theos.in router"

COUNT=4

for myHost in $HOSTS
do
  count=$(ping -c $COUNT $myHost | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
  if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
    # 100% failed 
    echo "Host : $myHost is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
  fi
done
```

However, it does not seem like an efficient solution.

[Linux: execute a command when network connection is restored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29513880/1772898) suggested using `ifplugd` or using `/etc/network/if-up.d/`.

There is another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/563747/206574) and a [blog post](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-7-run-script-when-network-interface-is-up-network-manager/) which mention using `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`.

As I am using Linux Mint, I think any solution revolving around [NetworkManager](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/NetworkManager.html) will be easier for me.

Comment: I have been using `--socket-timeout 3600` and my download did not stop for a long time now. However, the documentation is not clear and I am not sure what `--socket-timeout` actually does. I am not even sure whether (in the mean time) the vpn connection dropped and I got disconnected or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I wrote now that run on each line of `batch-file.txt` and run youtube-dl on it.
If there is no connection to the web site you trying to download from it will loop until connection restored (you should probably need to add some timeout on it since it will not stop.)
I used `curl` with expected `200` status code since if this don't work you probably won't be able to download.

The content of `batch-file.txt` is the same as before.

Running the script:

```
download.sh ./batch-file.txt {download_web_site_url}
# Example:
download.sh ./batch-file.txt google.com`
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# B"H

# Insted of using youtube-dl batch-file option read the file using bash.
URLS=$1 # "batch-file.txt"
# Pass the URL for site you trying to download from.
SITE_URL=$2

# This function check if url is returning 200 status code.
check_site_connection()
{
    # curl to 'your_site_url' with -I option for only the respons info only
    # pipe the respons tp awk with 'NR < 2' so only the first line with the status code is printed.
    # Return up if respons is 200.
    if [[ $(curl -Is $SITE_URL | awk 'NR < 2 {print $2}') == "200" ]];
    then
        echo up;
    else
        echo down;
    fi
}

# read the batch-file.
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # for each line in batch-file loop until conection to site is up with 2 seconds delay.
    while [[ $(check_site_connection) == "down" ]]
    do
        echo "waiting for internet conection"
        sleep 2
    done
    # run youtube-dl where line is the url to dowmload.
    ./youtube-dl "$line"
done < "$URLS"
```

**Edit**:

Just found this in the [README.md](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#how-do-i-download-only-new-videos-from-a-playlist) and tested it working .
This for case each line is a playlist and not separate video.

```
youtube-dl --download-archive archive.txt URL_TO_PLAYLIST
```

This will download only new videos each time you run so if you add `--download-archive archive.txt` to the script above in
`./youtube-dl --download-archive archive.txt "$line"`
So if it's start again it will go over all the playlist but will only start download from where it's stops.

Comment: why can't you use `pgrep youtube-dl` with `kill -STOP` and `kill -CONT`. Why don't you use https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/NetworkManager.html it has `vpn-up`, `vpn-down` and `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d`. I think it will be much reasonable solution.

Comment: First. The `curl` is running against the site without username and password, just the main page or something like this, so your user should not be associated with anything, maybe your IP.

Comment: Second. The `curl` command is running in loop if the status code is not ok = 200 so if that the case assuming there is no connection then the site not getting any requests.

Comment: Also you can use different site for the up check like `https://google.com` if you worry, but I think there is no problem using the download site URL

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. I am assuming `youtube-dl "$line"` will start over the playlist from the beginning in case the network goes down. Suppose I am on the 55th video of the playlist. Then it get disconnected. It will then start over from the beginning of that playlist. It will go through each link of the video in the playlist till it reach 56th fast. In that case, It will also block my account and trigger captcha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118862/discussion-between-blueray-and-shmuel).

Answer (score 1):

please use below code
*YoutubeDown.bash*

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $2 == 0 ]]
then
  if [[ ! -a youtubePlayListNames ]] 
  then
    youtube-dl --get-filename -o '%(title)s' $1  --restrict-filenames | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=",";}{print NR,$0}' > youtubePlayListNames
  fi
  for q in $(cat youtubePlayListNames)
  do
    row=$(echo $q | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
    fName=$(echo "$q" | awk -F',' '{print $2}')
    [[ $(find . -name *$fName* | wc -l) -eq 1 ]] && continue || break
  done
  youtube-dl --playlist-start $row -o '%(uploader)s/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' $1 --restrict-filenames
elif [[ $2 == 1 ]]
then
  youtube-dl -o '%(uploader)s/%(playlist)s/%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s' $1 --restrict-filenames
fi
```

I used like below:

- first time `YoutubeDown.bash https://youtubeURL 0`
- after that and when the download finished, I passed 1 as the second parameter to ensure all things downloaded
  I changed my code as previous unfortunately did not work.I test it and work well.

Comment: This answer seems to have nothing to do with my question. I awarded the bounty by mistake.

Comment: @blueray, I have worked on this issue to correct it. I'm very sorry for my previous wrong. hope you happy with it. I'm waiting for your response