# How to suspend and resume processes from a script

Tags: shell-script, job-control

I am trying to solve the problem given in
[pause youtube-dl when network is disconnected and resume when it is connected again](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627521/206574)

To stop and resume process, I have taken guideline from [How to suspend and resume processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2107/206574)

The problem is, the following works:

```
processid=$(pgrep youtube-dl)

kill -TSTP $processid
```

When I run the above script, The terminal running `youtube-dl` shows:

```
zsh: suspended  youtube-dl
% jobs
[1]  + suspended  youtube-dl
```

I have to go to the terminal and type the following command to continue the process:

```
% fg %1
[1]  + continued  youtube-dl
```

How to resume processes from a script instead of going to the terminal and typing a command?

Just for the sake of being thorough, If I run `tail -f ~/.xsession-errors`, I can pause it from the script using `kill -TSTP $processid` and resume it using `kill -CONT $processid`. It does not invoke the job control.

Comment: Just a comment about `pgrep youtube-dl` + `kill -TSTP`.  This would be much better written as `pkill -TSTP youtube-dl`.

Comment: `kill -CONT` should work (and, of course, `pkill -CONT youtube-dl` as well).

Comment: @berndbausch Try it with e.g. `top`, or any other command.  Sending `CONT` to it will not put it back into the foreground of the interactive shell where it was started.

Comment: @Kusalananda I tried it with `top` and confirmed what you said. However, I then tried it with this snippet: `( while :; do echo $i; sleep 2; i=$((i+1)); done )` also running in the foreground, and that could be stopped and continued with SIGTSTP and SIGCONT, respectively, although it was continued in the background. `top` reads from the terminal, which causes problems when running in the background. Since `youtube-dl` is unlikely to require terminal input or running in the foreground, SIGCONT should work in this particular case.

Comment: we can get the terminal name using `ptsname=$(ps aux | grep 38648 | awk '{ print $7 }')` and continue that process in that terminal using `kill -CONT 39905 > /dev${ptsname}`. However, I am not still sure how the complete script will look like.

Comment: If you prefix your youtube-dl command with `setsid` it will run in a new terminal session so you can kill it with `-stop` and `-cont` without the change in state being seen by the shell.